# How to import values from txt to mysql db(pdo) with php

Tags: php, mysql, file, pdo

I want to import some values to my db from txt file. File scructure looks like this:

```
Title: Blazing Saddles
Release Year: 1974
Format: VHS
Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn

Title: Casablanca
Release Year: 1942
Format: DVD
Stars: Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre

Title: Charade
Release Year: 1953
Format: DVD
Stars: Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy
```

I use this form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Add film</title>
    <?php require 'menu.php'; ?>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Add films from .txt file</h2>
<p>If you want to add new films to our collection, you need to fill in the form below</p>
<div class="container">
    <form action="importAction.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="file" type="file" style="margin-bottom: 10px" accept=".txt">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this method to add new items to my db:

```
public function addFilm($name, $year, $format, $actors)
    {
        return $this->db->setQuery("INSERT INTO {$this->config[self::DB_NAME]} 
        (name, year, format, actors) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$year}', '{$format}', '{$actors}')");
    }
```

How can I do that? Can you, please, help me with that?

Comment: You could use `file(..)` to read the textfile line by line, then use `explode(': ',$line)` with some logic to get the values behind the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file approach is a good idea, I used a very simple RegEx approach to read the data from the file:

```
$regex = '/Title:\s(.*)\r\nRelease Year:\s(.*)\r\nFormat:\s(.*)\r\nStars:\s(.*)\r\n/';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// need validation for matches structure of course

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $this->addFilm($match[1], $match[2], $match[3], $match[4]);
}
```

Output of matches is as follows

```
    /*
    array:3 [
      0 => array:5 [
        0 => """
          Title: Blazing Saddles\r\n
          Release Year: 1974\r\n
          Format: VHS\r\n
          Stars: Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn\r\n
          """
        1 => "Blazing Saddles"
        2 => "1974"
        3 => "VHS"
        4 => "Mel Brooks, Clevon Little, Harvey Korman, Gene Wilder, Slim Pickens, Madeline Kahn"
      ]
      1 => array:5 [
        0 => """
          Title: Casablanca\r\n
          Release Year: 1942\r\n
          Format: DVD\r\n
          Stars: Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre\r\n
          """
        1 => "Casablanca"
        2 => "1942"
        3 => "DVD"
        4 => "Humphrey Bogart, Ingrid Bergman, Claude Rains, Peter Lorre"
      ]
      2 => array:5 [
        0 => """
          Title: Charade\r\n
          Release Year: 1953\r\n
          Format: DVD\r\n
          Stars: Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy\r\n
          """
        1 => "Charade"
        2 => "1953"
        3 => "DVD"
        4 => "Audrey Hepburn, Cary Grant, Walter Matthau, James Coburn, George Kennedy"
      ]
    ]
     */
```

Please take into consideration that the regex is not very error safe. Any wrong character, missing line ending etc. can lead to an error. 
But this is only for demonstration, how you can do it.